# Call another Controller's Method

Tags: angularjs

I have a `NavBarCtrl` which is in partial page. In this page i have a Search box with a button Search.

On this btn click, i want to call `DashBoardCtrl` method `listRecords()`.

I am getting all the searched values by setting them to `$rootScope` in `DashBoardCtrl`.

How to call another controller's method?

Here is my relevant code :-

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
                <img src="/images/menu-search.png" alt="Search" title="Search" ng-click="openSearch()" />
            </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <div ng-form="searchPatient" class="searchPatient" id="searchPatient">                            
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Last Name</td>
                                <td><input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" ng-model="search.lastname"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>First Name</td>
                                <td><input name="firstname" id="firstname" type="text"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Date of Birth</td>
                                <td><input name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth" type="text"></td>
                            </tr>                              
                        </table>                            
                        <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="listRecords(1)">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is DashBoardCtrl html parent of NavBarCtrl html, then you can directly call listRecords with parameters.

Comment: It is not in parent...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Angular JS `$watch` , [factory](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) or you can declare that method as `$rootScope.listRecords`  to achieve this tasks

### Using Factory  - (Recommended)

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/98/)**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('testFactory', function(){
    return {
        listRecords: function(){
            console.log('listRecords');
        }
    }               
});


app.controller('NavBarCtrl', function ($scope, testFactory) {

    $scope.clickAction = function () {
        console.log('clickAction');
        $scope.fromService = testFactory.listRecords();
    }
});

app.controller('DashBoardCtrl', function ($scope, testFactory) {

    $scope.fromService = testFactory.listRecords();
});
```

### Declaring the method with $rootScope

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/95/)**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('NavBarCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

   $scope.clickAction = function()
    {
        $scope.listRecords();
        console.log('clickAction');
    }
});

app.controller('DashBoardCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.listRecords = function()
    {
        console.log('listRecords');
    }
});
```

### Without declaring the method with $rootScope

The below code shows how you can trigger another controller method without making the method as rootScope

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/94/)**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('NavBarCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

   $scope.clickAction = function()
    {
        $rootScope.trigger = 1;
        console.log('clickAction');
    }
});

app.controller('DashBoardCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('trigger', function()
    {
      $scope.listRecords();
    }, true);

    $scope.listRecords = function()
    {
        console.log('listRecords');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a clever, but if they're looking for a quick and dirty solution, they may be better suited using $broadcast from $rootScope, while listening with $on in the destination controller. Ultimately, I agree with @ivami, that a service would be best here.

Comment: I find that relying on putting stuff on `$rootScope` comes back to haunt you at some point. Typically when doing unit-testing. At the very least, use `$broadcast` instead of `$watch`.

Comment: Both above methods work...But when i run the recommended one....as my search is in `navbar` and it runs everytime on page load...i have put an `alert` in `listRecords()`....Alert runs 4 times when i first login...!

Comment: @Anup You can also use Factory Services providers that are available in AngularJS, as suggested by MarcKline and ivarni that will be a clean way...

Answer (score 2):

A controller that is the child of another can access a function from it's parent via `$scope` if the parent controller puts it on its own `$scope`. Alternatively anything that is put on `$rootScope` is accessible from any controller, but that is a very brittle solution. It sounds like your function really should be in a `service`.

Answer (score 2):

By using a service such as a factory, you would ensure both better testability and readability of your code. $rootScope is like the global namespace of Angular - you should use it very sparingly, if ever at all.

I made a [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IkiuOx7VQ9bc0YsLwkpc?p=preview) to demonstrate a simplified version of a search service whose query originates from one controller and results appear in another.

This type of code can be both simple and clean:

```
.controller('NavController', function($scope, Search) {
  $scope.change = function(query){
    Search.query(query);
  }
})
.controller('DashController', function($scope, Search) {
  $scope.search = Search;
})
.factory('Search', function(Data){
  var search = {results: []};

  search.query = function(query){
    search.results = [];
    Data.forEach(function(item){
      if (item.color == query) { search.results.push(item) }
    });
    return search;
  }

  return search;
})
```

It sounds as if you've decided to go with a solution using `$rootScope`, but I urge you to reconsider. Investing some time now to establish good practices will pay off later, perhaps many times over.