# Problems Monitoring Changes on {{values}} to Trigger Directive manipulations of DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I am working with two different controllers.

The first controller has two buttons on the front end.  One is an increment button and another is a decrement button.  When a button is pressed a value representing which button was pressed is stored in the $rootScope and an event is broadcast to let the second controller know to spring into action.

The second controller displays (using ngRepeat) each element in an object.  In this application each element represents a student. When an increment or decrement button is pressed, the second controller must update the grade for each of the students (we're implementing a curve).

```
[{
"name": "value",
"grade": "value"
},{
"name": "value",
"grade": "value"
},{
.
.
.
}];
```

I am trying to write a directive that will add a class from [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) before the button's value has changed, which will trigger a fade away animation.  Then I would like to have the animation complete and update each grade.  Finally, I would like to remove the class for the first animation (fadeOut) and add another class (fadeIn).  When the fadeIn animation is finished, I would like to remove the fadeIn class so future animations (increment and decrement button presses) load correctly.

There is also an angular way to delay each transition (.ng-enter-stagger and .ng-leave-stagger), which I would like to utilize, but I can't even get my directive to see changes on a student's grade.

I've tried passing the class object to my directive using :

```
scope: {
            class: '='
        },
```

so that the directive has access to $watch changes within the student objects, but without much luck.  I've tried using $observe as well, but with no luck either.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?  Should I be using postLink functions? My JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shawful/Yxjr3/4/).

AHH! This should be easy :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set `scope: {}` for your directive in order to access parent scope values. In fact, here it is a counterproductive measure.

Instead, add a `$watch` to your link function, and pass `true` as the third parameter. This will instruct the function to do a deep inspection of the object's values for changes instead of a shallow comparison which will always compare the object reference to itself and therefore will never fire the callback.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    $timeout(function(){$animate.removeClass(element, 'animated bounce');},1000);
    scope.$watch('class', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue !== oldValue) { 
          console.log('new value:', newValue);
      }
    }, true);
}
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcolepsy/N3h2R/)

You may also find that life is much easier by several measures if you create a service to manage your data and [cross-component methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752469/call-another-controllers-method/23753552#23753552) instead of using $rootScope properties and events.